# MySql library not found

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a MySql database and I try logging into it using `MySqlConnection()`, but it seems I don't have the MySql library. I understood `Connector/Net` should be downloaded, so I did. Unfortunately it's still not working. Any solutions please?

Comment: Show your code and the error message.

Comment: Actually there's no code to show. I tried using `SqlConnection` but it's apparently not working with MySql, so I searched the web and found many uses `MySqlConnection` so I tried it but I don't have the library so it doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing Connector/Net, you'll need to add it as a reference in your project. Right-click on your project, Add Reference..., MySQL.Data should be listed on the .Net tab. If it isn't, you can copy the assembly from "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net \Assemblies" into your bin folder then add the reference via the "Add Reference / Browse" tab.

You'll also need a reference to it in your class...

```
using MySQL.Data
```

For more, maybe this will help... http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL